# How to rewrite 'with update' to postgresql 9.0

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.0

Following SQL statement was written for PostgreSQL 9.4.15 and it's working on this version of PostgreSQL.

```
WITH const_threshold AS (
    SELECT max(id)
    FROM temp_menu_items AS val
)
UPDATE temp_menu_items
SET id        = id + (SELECT parent_id
                      FROM temp_menu_items
                      WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
                      ORDER BY parent_id DESC
                      LIMIT 1) + (SELECT *
                                  FROM const_threshold)
  , parent_id = parent_id + (SELECT parent_id
                             FROM temp_menu_items
                             WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
                             ORDER BY parent_id DESC
                             LIMIT 1) + (SELECT *
                                         FROM const_threshold);
```

Reffering to docs there is no with update in PostgreSQL 9.0
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-with.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html

**How to rewrite that statment for PostgreSQL 9.0?**

Or more generally:

**There is any way to use 'with update' (or equivalent) in 9.0 version of PostgreSQL?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CTE (`WITH foo AS ...`) can broadly be thought of as a "shared sub-query", and in many cases can be replaced with a normal sub-query.

This is one of those cases: the only use of `const_threshold` is in the sub-query `(SELECT * FROM const_threshold)`, so you can replace that directly with the full sub-query `(SELECT max(id) FROM temp_menu_items)`.

This isn't always possible - for instance, CTEs can be "recursive" in a way that normal sub-queries cannot - and may not result in the same query plan, so the general answer is that there is no direct way to do this without upgrading to a newer version of PostgreSQL.

For this example, I believe the result should be equivalent, you just need to write the same sub-query out twice (but the current version isn't exactly concise anyway).